# Normalize movie titles using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a php script that takes a list of movies from a 
webservice, and store'em into a database.

Nothing fancy, 
the only thing that I need to address now is a *sort title* which is the titile
of the movie stripped (where necessary) from the usuals '*The*' / '*An*' / '*A*'.

e.g.

- The Dark Knight
- An Education
- A Separation

should become

- Dark Knight
- Education
- Separation

simple as that, but considering my noobness in the regex field, I'm calling out for a help.
hope I made myself clear. Ask for clarifications if you find yourself in doubt.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I wouldn't strip the title completely, but rather I'd turn `The Dark Knight` into `Dark Knight, The`. You should probably preserve the original title because the title is specific to the movie.

Comment: No regex needed here. you could use `trim(str_replace('The', '', 'The Dark Knight'));`

Comment: What would you do about `The Good, The Bad and They Ugly` ?

Comment: @Baba, I need to strip just the first occurrence of it, so the first 'The'.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I don't need to preserve that, because this information is just used for sorting purposes and won't be showed to the user.

Comment: I'd keep the titles as they are and have a 2nd field for alt title, and shift the "The " onto the end as @Jeremy1026 suggests.  Is this because you are concerned about an A-Z listing or search results?  If its an A-Z listing I'd display both so that The Dark Knight appears in both the letters D and T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$titles = array("The Dark Knight","An Education","A Separation");
$words = array('a','the','an');
$regex = '/\b^(' . implode('|', $words) . ')\b/i' ;

echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $titles as $title ) {
    echo preg_replace($regex, '', $title), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
 Dark Knight
 Education
 Separation
```

Comment: it works like a charm, and +1 for the elegance. there's just a bracket typo in your code (in the preg_replace), plus the fact that the result of preg_replace call should be trimmed, for the rest it's totally awsum! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(The|An|A) (.+)$
```

use `\2` to return the film title without the definite article, eg `Dark Knight`

or use `\2, \1` to return `Dark Knight, The`